# Is this the right characterization of the function?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Is it possible to say that $h(x)$ is a concave function if $$h(x)=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$ where $f(x)$ is concave function and $g(x)$ is a convex function.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, consider $f(x)= x-1$ and $g(x)=x+1$. [image]